# How to use a loop counter to modify values for a hyperlink constructor

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What I'm trying to do is while using a for loop, use the loop counter `i` to modify values that already have a base number assigned to them in a html element. This is so i can construct multiple hyperlinks with different values. To elaborate here is my html code

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var ids = [];
var values = [];
var links = [];
var MasLink = "";
var words = []
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  ids[i] = inputs[i].id;
  values[i] = (inputs[i].value * (1 + (0.1 * i)));
  console.log(i, values)
};
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  links[i] = "http://data.sparkfun.com/input/public_key?private_key=private_key&altitude=" + values[2] + "&battry_voltage=" + values[3] + "&day=" + values[4] + "&external_temp=" + values[5] + "&heading=" + values[6] + "&internal_temp=" + values[7] + "&latitude=" + values[8] + "&longitude=" + values[9] + "&minute=" + values[10] + "&month=" + values[11] + "&second=" + values[12] + "&speed=" + values[13] + "&year=" + values[14];
  words[i] = "<small>" + ids[2] + ":" + values[2] + ", " + ids[3] + ":" + values[3] + ", " + ids[4] + ":" + values[4] + ", " + ids[5] + ":" + values[5] + ", " + ids[6] + ":" + values[6] + ", " + ids[7] + ":" + values[7] + ", " + ids[8] + ":" + values[8] + ", " + ids[9] + ":" + values[9] + ", " + ids[10] + ":" + values[10] + ", " + ids[11] + ":" + values[11] + ", " + ids[12] + ":" + values[12] + ", " + ids[13] + ":" + values[13] + ", " + ids[14] + ":" + values[14] + ", " + ids[15] + ":" + values[15] + ", " + "</small>"
  MasLink += "<a href=" + links[i] + ">" + words[i] + "</a><br><br>"
  document.getElementById("BuiltLink").innerHTML = MasLink
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="frm1">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>PublicKey:</td>
          <td>PrivateKey:</td>
          <td>latitude:</td>
          <td>longitude:</td>
          <td>altitude:</td>
          <td>heading:</td>
          <td>speed:</td>
          <td>external_temp:</td>
          <td>internal_temp:</td>
          <td>battry_voltage:</td>
          <td>hour:</td>
          <td>minute:</td>
          <td>second:</td>
          <td>year:</td>
          <td>month:</td>
          <td>day:</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="PublicKey" value="PublicKey"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="PrivateKey" value="PrivateKey"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="latitude" value="33.505304"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="longitude" value="-86.807809"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="altitude" value="5"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="heading" value="13.7"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="speed" value="3"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="external_temp" value="72"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="internal_temp" value="70"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="battry_voltage" value="12.7"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="hour" value="10"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="minute" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="second" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="year" value="2015"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="month" value="6"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="day" value="29"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="BuildLink()" class="btn btn-default">Gimme Link!</button>
  </form>
  <div>
    <a id="printlink" href=""></a>
  </div>
  <div id="BuiltLink">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Problem is I'm getting the same value each time the code loops. Which shouldn't happen if `i` is increasing in value for each loop. Please let me know if you need me to explain clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of working on this code I figured out my initial thought process was wrong. So I deleted the code and rewrote it. Basically I had to sit down and actually draw a concept on a massive white board. Here is a plunker with the finished code.

http://embed.plnkr.co/HcVfHQ3U5WkLDz1fWfOI/preview

I hope this can help someone else too. Feel free to ask me questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should persist the value of the i variable in another variable with different scope that your BuildLink function because everytime you call this function all values are reseted.

```
var increase = 0;

function BuildLink() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    var ids = [];
    var values = [];
    var links = [];
    var MasLink = "";
    var words = [];
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        ids[i] = inputs[i].id;
        increase = increase + i;
        values[i] = (inputs[i].value * (1 + (0.1 * increase)));
        console.log(i, values);
    };
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        links[i] = "http://data.sparkfun.com/input/public_key?private_key=private_key&altitude=" + values[2] + "&battry_voltage=" + values[3] + "&day=" + values[4] + "&external_temp=" + values[5] + "&heading=" + values[6] + "&internal_temp=" + values[7] + "&latitude=" + values[8] + "&longitude=" + values[9] + "&minute=" + values[10] + "&month=" + values[11] + "&second=" + values[12] + "&speed=" + values[13] + "&year=" + values[14];
        words[i] = "<small>" + ids[2] + ":" + values[2] + ", " + ids[3] + ":" + values[3] + ", " + ids[4] + ":" + values[4] + ", " + ids[5] + ":" + values[5] + ", " + ids[6] + ":" + values[6] + ", " + ids[7] + ":" + values[7] + ", " + ids[8] + ":" + values[8] + ", " + ids[9] + ":" + values[9] + ", " + ids[10] + ":" + values[10] + ", " + ids[11] + ":" + values[11] + ", " + ids[12] + ":" + values[12] + ", " + ids[13] + ":" + values[13] + ", " + ids[14] + ":" + values[14] + ", " + ids[15] + ":" + values[15] + ", " + "</small>"
        MasLink += "<a href=" + links[i] + ">" + words[i] + "</a><br><br>"
        document.getElementById("BuiltLink").innerHTML = MasLink;
    }
}
```

In my opinion you should use Math.random to generate random values instead of just increasing a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, most cases when i need values to change i would use Math.random. but this is only part of a project that needs values based on gps locations. The whole project is basiclly a advanced map api to keep track of a weather balloon.